How can we know how good a TRNG is?
Imagine that a perfect TRNG generates 100 bits, which are then fed into a high quality PRNG such as ChaCha20, which generates 1000 bits.
How many bits of entropy is in the 1000 bits? Depends on who is looking. We know the algorithm, so from our point of view there is only 100 bits of entropy in total. To an outsider, such as running it through a test suite (NIST SP 800-22, Diehard, etc) it will appear as 1000 bits of entropy or close to it.
I wonder if what we said about the PRNG can also be said about the TRNG? We assume that a proven TRNG, such a ring oscillator with appropriate signal conditioning, gives close to 1 bit of entropy per bit generated. This physical process appears random to us because of the high degree of complexity of our universe. It passes the test suites, so we just accept it as a "true" random number generator. But we don't have a complete theoretical foundation for how the bits are generated, so we can't really tell with 100% certainty. Tomorrow it might turn out that this design was doing something akin to a PRNG but through a physical process. After all, the universe itself is a form of insanely complex algorithm.
And if we talk about CSRNGs, entropy isn't the only thing that matters about the output. Here we also only have blunt tools to make sure a RNG is cryptographically secure. Again, track record is what matters. We pick the design that no one has broken yet.
So I guess that what I'm really asking is: The proven TRNGs we have, would it be fair to say that we really don't know how good they are, just that so far they have not failed our tests?

"And if we talk about CSRNGs, entropy isn't the only thing that matters about the output. Here we also only have blunt tools to make sure a RNG is cryptographically secure." Uh, yeah, that's how every part of modern crypto-analysis operates. You've just called the whole of modern cryptography a blunt tool. That's so close to an insult that I think it is brave that you dared to post it on this cryptography site ;)

@MaartenBodewes That was not my intention. I'm just a novice trying to understand this complex subject. :-)


How many bits of entropy is in the 1000 bits? To an outsider, such as running it through a test suite (NIST SP 800-22, Diehard, etc) it will appear as 1000 bits of entropy or close to it.

Well, no - if we assume that the outsider knows the algorithm (and we always assume he does), then he will also know that the output has 100 bits [1] of entropy.
Now, a statistical test (SP 800-22 or Diehard would require far more input than 1000 bits, but that isn't the point of your question) would be fooled by such a scheme, but all that indicates is that a statistical test can be very bad at estimating entropy.  For example, if we give the test the first 1000 bits of $\pi$, it will also think it's quite good, even though there is no entropy in $\pi$.
However, your real question is:

The proven TRNGs we have, would it be fair to say that we really don't know how good they are, just that so far they have not failed our tests?

Actually, we have TRNGs with some theory around them.  For starters, there are QRNGs (Quantum Random Number Generators) which directly rely on Quantum Mechanics to generate randomness.  Hence, if the device is working as designed and we believe that the Quantum Mechanics is an approximately correct description of our universe (which appears to be an extremely safe assumption), then we can safely deduce that the output we get has some true randomness [2].
If we look at a ring oscillator based TRNG (which are by far the most common, because they're so cheap), we will see that (assuming the design is correct) that the entropy we get is actually from the thermal noise within the device (as phonons bouncing around the device slightly increase or slightly decrease the transition times of the gates).  Thermal noise is chaotic, and so we do get some randomness (although characterizing the amount is a rather nontrivial process).
And so, yes, we do have TRNGs that appear to be trustable.

[1]: Pedantically speaking, it might have somewhat less, if ChaCha20 happens to generate the same output for two different inputs.  This doesn't appear to be likely, but it is unproven.
[2]: It might not be "full entropy", because of imperfections in our device, however (in my view) that is not important - if we get collect enough data so that, over those series of output bits, we have at least (say) 256 bits of minentropy, we're golden - we can hand that off to a good CSPRNG, and have it generate bits that are indistinguishable from random for any realistic (computationally bounded) adversary, which is our real goal.

Thanks for the answer. My real issue is rather that we can't quantify exactly how good a ring oscillator is, because our current tools are too blunt for it. It might as well be on the order of the ShaSha20 algorithm. Both pass all relevant tests. That's my objection to calling hardware RNGs "true" RNGs. It might intuitively feel like a hardware RNG must be better, given the dependency on thermal noise, etc. Lots of factors. But do we actually KNOW that?

@BjörnMorén: actually, what's important is not "exactly how good the RO is", but instead coming up with a lower bound.  As long as we have that (e.g. we know that a string of $x$ bits output has a minentropy of $x/5$), then we just oversample to get to the amount of minentropy we need.  And, because of the analysis that can be done looking at changes in gate transition times due to thermal noise, we can come up with defensible bounds.  Now, I expect that most people implementing ROs don't go to that extent - but, they really should.

@BjörnMorén: and, as for calling a RO a "TRNG", well, I try to avoid that (because just the raw output will have correlations).  Instead, I call it an "entropy source", because that better describes what it is (and what it should be used as)

Thanks. I guess it depends on what the RNG is used for. If we want a CSRNG, min-entropy is only part of the picture. A PRNG can generate a stream with high min-entropy but that is still unsuitable for encryption. The ultimate test suite would be one that tests for all known and possible future algorithms that might have generated the stream, which we of course will never have, unless there is some fundamental break-through in information theory. I guess the gist of your post is that the RNG only has to be "good enough", which is a good attitude to solve practical problems.

There are several separate issues here. I would divide the topic into evaluation of random sources, security assumptions of post-processing, different ways in which these security assumptions can fail, and then ways in which implementation assumptions will fail. I'll briefly deal with each in turn.
Random sources are not usually evaluated by black-box testing. Instead, one relies on background knowledge about the processes that generate entropy within the device, which allows modelling them on the physical level or at least on the level of describing them as concrete stochastic processes. This knowledge can guide the selection of appropriate statistical tests. These are commonly also used to detect failure modes of the device before it outputs any bad randomness, so they are not a one-time thing and the tests don't have to detect arbitrary problems but only some that are realistic based on the available background theory.
Given that understanding, it's then usually apparent that the raw random source will contain some biases that cannot be entirely eliminated by simple post-processing. Moreover, there may be some potential for sources to deteriorate or fail without online tests being able to notice it. To mitigate these risks, we employ post-processing techniques using Cryptographically Secure Pseudorandom Number Generators (CSPRNGs).
Now, it's important to note that CSPRNGs rely on computational hardness assumptions, which, while widely accepted, remain unproven. For instance, the common belief that $P \neq NP$ lacks formal proof. If $P = NP$ were true and the algorithm that made it so were efficient in practice, an adversary could recover the seed from a small portion of the output, rendering the remaining stream devoid of entropy when conditioned on this knowledge. Many people will say that this is a purely academic point, because nobody in their right mind believes that $P=NP$, but proof we have not.
There are also less academic failure modes. Consider a concrete example: a 100-bit seeded ChaCha CSPRNG. A hundred bits is a lot of work factor, and very smart people have looked at ChaCha, so this could seem secure. However, quantum attackers might reduce the work factor to 50 bits, albeit with poor parallelization. Time-memory tradeoffs with precomputation would also reduce the online work factor considerably, at the cost of a $2^{100}$ precomputation and a lot of memory. Cryptanalytic attacks could also make it possible to reverse the key stream just for this one cipher, although nobody knows of any.
Below the level of true attacks, it's worth noting that well-regarded primitives like ChaCha may exhibit properties distinctly different from truly random outputs. For instance, ChaCha's output is the bitwise addition of two weak key streams (that are weak in the sense that if we saw short portions of them individually, we could easily predict them). While this is not believed to be exploitable, I don't think I have seen a proof of indistinguishability for that class of constructions from the output of a keyed random mapping transforming, say, a counter to keystream output.
Lastly, seed entropy can also get compromised by things like side channels. If that happens, entropy conditioned on the side-channel knowledge also drops to zero for the rest of the key stream unless reseeding is done regularly.
To answer your question directly, I would not agree with saying we do "not know" how good our RNGs are - there is theory behind the choice of statistical tests, it is possible to build several layers of fail-safes and security margins in, and the computational hardness assumptions we build on are not controversial - but the knowledge we do have is not knowledge that has the level of mathematical certainty. It would be fair to say that any concrete constructions could horribly fail, but if they did so, this would likely be the result of fundamentally new attack techniques and not of the type of incremental progress that we can engineer against.

You realise that a proper TRNG has nought to do with CSPRNGs?  There are no seeds.

@PaulUszak I suppose you are referring to the first-to-last paragraph of the answer? I'm assuming that this is indeed about CSPRNG's, but I have to admit that this isn't made clear or explicit. I think this answer would benefit from some restructuring to indicate when it is about TRNG's, CSPRNG's and the relationship between the two regarding entropy estimation and security.

I somewhat doubt that the $P = / \neq NP$ question really helps here – it is about asymptotic behavior, and doesn't tell very much about any specific CSPRNG with a concrete security parameter.

Thanks for clarifying this topic to me. Your last paragraph sums it up well. However I would add that from my perspective as a novice/outsider, it seems like you are trying to dodge the fact that a TRNG really is a black box. Or perhaps I should say that it would be irresponsible to not treat it as a black box (with potential for cryptography), when designing a critical system. That is what I tried to hint at in my OP. Just like a transistor is also a black box. But it doesn't matter as long as it works well enough with the added layers, which it seems to do.


The proven TRNGs we have, would it be fair to say that we really don't know how good they are, just that so far they have not failed our tests?

Hi again.
Can I suggest that there are no "proven" TRNGs unless you've built it yourself?  Something like a diode based entropy source is indeed provably random, yet that's not a TRNG.  When you add on the extraction software, obfuscate the C code, encapsulate the package in opaque resin and then rely on the US Digital Millennium Copyright Act (DMCA) and the State to incarcerate anyone trying to determine how such a device works, where's the "proof"? Computational indistinguishably means that unless you've built it yourself, that supplier can easily cheat you.

After all, the universe itself is a form of insanely complex algorithm.

That's not actually true according to our current understanding.  Quantum indeterminacy  and the Heisenberg Uncertainty principle dictate that some very small things do indeed act randomly.  The diode example above is such, which produces an output that is only predictable in general stochastic terms.
That means no amount of testing or probing can precisely model them. Ever.  So no, that is not a fair assessment.
Also look up Kolmogorov Complexity. It will answer :-

Imagine that a perfect TRNG generates 100 bits, which are then fed into a high quality PRNG such as ChaCha20, which generates 1000 bits.


How many bits of entropy is in the 1000 bits?

Answer ~ 100 bits + $\lfloor  \text{size} \rfloor$ of ChaCha20's algorithm.  Which of course in the long run = 100 as $ \frac{\text{size}}{\text{|output|}} \to 0 $.

Hi again Paul. "Something like a diode based entropy source is indeed provably random". How do we know that? AFAIK we have not yet come up with tests that are good enough to tell a ShaSha20 stream from an diode avalanche TRNG stream. We might assume it from what you write here, but where is the proof? Sure, we use these TRNGs all the time and they seem secure enough. What I'm after here is the theoretical foundation for why, plus the experiments/test suites that prove it.

Regarding quantum indeterminacy: Well I guess it depends on whether there is determinism in the foundation of the universe, and it just looks indeterminable to us because we don't have all the data. We will probably never know.

@BjörnMorén: well, things like "Bell Tests" show that there are measurements that cannot be explained by "hidden variables", that is, data that is there that we don't see.  You might want to look that up if you are honest in wanting to know more.

Thanks Poncho. @BjörnMorén follow his suggestion and look up indeterminacy. It's a common fallacy to assume we can predict electron motion/location if we just measure betterer.

"How many bits of entropy is in the 1000 bits?. Answer ~ 100 bits + $\lfloor  \text{size} \rfloor$ of ChaCha20's algorithm. Did you just use an algorithm to estimate the average Kolmogorov Complexity of a deterministic algorithm and did you then equate that estimate of complexity with entropy? As an aside $output$ is not in the function you've given to calculate that complexity, so I don't see how $size \over |output|$ can change the result.

@poncho, paul-uszak : We're getting away from the main topic here, but I'd say that Bell Tests only test for local hidden variables, and that the Universe might be completely deterministic but our limited understanding make us not observe it that way. There is Superdeterminism. However, I agree that when we look at a ring oscillator all evidence currently point to that it is indeterminate in nature. I'll concede that. Ok, so where are the tests that prove our theory? In what tests does it perform better than a PRNG?
